# Use mget to download files in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am creating a bash script for centos 7 and I want that `mget` download me the files who be named in a file. How I can make this?

I tried with these codes "prueba" is the file where is ubicated the filename:

```
mget prueba
mget prueba/*
```

Thank you for helpme

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [this mget](https://github.com/weaming/mget)? If so, it's not directly possible to use this utility to download a list of URL's you specify in a file.

You can however use [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to simulate the same effect:

```
xargs -n 1 -a prueba mget
```

This would effectively call mget for each line in the file you specify (e.g. `prueba`).

Comment: It looks like mget only supports http/https. If you want something that supports ftp try [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). It's considerably more standard and comes pre-installed on a lot of *-nix distributions. It also supports a load of other protocols in addition to http/ftp.

Answer (score 0):

This shoud solve your problem:

```
xargs -n 1 -P 8 -a prueba wget
```

- `-a` Use file as input
- `-n1` Use one argument at a time
- `-P8` Use up to 8 processes (no need to use `mget`, since `xargs` handles the parallel downloads)